# Application not working after modify dispatcher-servlet.xml in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, dispatcher, applicationcontext

I'm new to the spring framework. Currently I studying about spring framework. I follow this tutorials,
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/quickstart-webapps-spring.html

http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html

But I have a problem in both example, after adding beans to dispather-servlet.xml and modify application-contex.xml application is not deploy. It gives following massage.

In-place deployment at C:\Users...\Documents\NetBeansProjects\springapp\build\web
Initializing...
deploy?DEFAULT=C:\Users...\Documents\NetBeansProjects\springapp\build\web&name=springapp&contextroot=/springapp&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 3.1.2 
 Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: springapp.web.HelloController. Please see server.log for more details.
C:\Users...\Documents\NetBeansProjects\springapp\nbproject\build-impl.xml:728: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)

Please help to solve this.

Thank you in advance.

PS:-

@shazinltc -
Here is my dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"  p:suffix=".jsp" />
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />       
      <bean name="helloService" class="service.HelloService" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve my problem with following tutorial.

https://sites.google.com/site/springmvcnetbeans/step-by-step/

This tutorial is quite simple and more specific and descriptive in each step. I recommend this tutorial for beginners in spring.